# import rich_ipython_widget in a py2exe excutable

Tags: python, pyqt, ipython, py2exe

I am building an executable for my python software in which I have an interactive python terminal widget. It works perfectly if I run it in python, but it fails to run if I double click the .exe I constructed with py2exe. I isolated the problem and it drops down to a simple line of code:

```
from IPython.qt.console.rich_ipython_widget import RichIPythonWidget
```

if I put this unique line in a test.py file and I run it, there is no error. now I build the .exe with py2exe using the following setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from py2exe.build_exe import py2exe

setup(name = "Test", 
      console=[{"script":"testShell.py"}], options={})
```

then the resulting error message, when running the executable, is:

```
ImportError: 
Could not load requested Qt binding. Please ensure that
PyQt4 >= 4.7 or PySide >= 1.0.3 is available,
and only one is imported per session.

Currently-imported Qt library:   'pyqt'
PyQt4 installed:                 False
PySide >= 1.0.3 installed:       False
Tried to load:                   ['pyqt']
```

Since the app is working in python, this means that the problem is not that pyqt is not installed, but not found.

I am facing a wall here, let me know if you have a clue?

Comment: It looks like py2exe can't figure out that either PyQt4 or PySide is needed. Most often such error can't be corrected by helping py2exe a bit by using the packages options, e.g. something like optins={"packages: 'PyQt4}

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did try to add this package as you suggested. But this didn't help:
    packages =['matplotlib','pylab','pytz','tables','numexpr','PyQt4']

Comment: What error getting now when you run the executable?  Still the same, or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this exact same issue by modifying the file `"qt_loader.py"`  (in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\IPython\external`).

What you have to do it just force the `"has_binding"` function to return `"True"`. 
The problems lies in the `"imp.find_module"` which does not work with **py2exe**!

Here, this is really a **"false positive",** (i.e. a test that fails while there is no actual problem). Skipping the test solves the issue.